# How to return an Int from one method to another in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(){
  getNumber();
  printNumber();
  int x;
}

public static int getNumber(){
  int x = 5;
  return(x);
}

public static void printNumber(){

  System.out.println(x);
}
```

I am a total beginner, sorry for such a simple question. The above fragment of code is what I tried.

Comment: `int x = getNumber();`

Comment: `int val = getNumber();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = getNumber();
        printNumber(x);
    }

    public static int getNumber() {
        int x = 5;
        return x;
    }

    public static void printNumber(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
public static int getNumber(){
  int x = 5;
  return(x);
}
```

Creates **another** local variable x. So that assignment affects only the `x` that "belongs" to `getNumber()`. The static field `x` of your enclosing class stays at its initial value of 0.

But there you go:

```
public static void printNumber(){
  x = getNumer();
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

Of course, a first step for writing more reasonable code: you decide whether you want to have that "global" field that all methods of your class can use, **or** if you want to not do that.

Meaning: either you use that field, then your method just updates `x`, and the other method prints it. **Or** your class doesn't have that field, and your two methods work by `getNumber()` returning a value, and then printing *that* returned result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you firstly explain, what you want to do by this code?

Let's go through your code:

I concider method printNumber() to be excess because It's just wrapper for System.out.println method, we can use it derectly in our code.

Method getNumber() could receive some paramater, for example getNumber(int a). With such improvement we would be able to call getNumber from our main method and pass to it variable that we define in main method. Than getNumber could perform some operation, forexample a * a and return this result.

Also main method of java programm must look like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x = 5;
  int resultOfGetNumber = getNumber(x);
  System.out.println(resultOfGetNumber);
}

public static int getNumber(int a){
  return(a * a);
}
```

So we define variable x in our main method and passes it to the getNumber method, which returns the square of received variable. Then in main method we assing result of getNumber method to the int variable resultOfGetNumber. Then we pass resultOfGetNumber  to the System.out.println method, which prints this variable to the console.